# Will a banner with CTA (Call to Action) drive more users click than banner without CTA (Call to Action)?

Tags: layout, design, homepage, placement

I'm just curious that a banner with CTA (Call to Action) will drive more users to click than banner without CTA (Call to Action).

The banners will be placed on homepage as a slider.

Comment: Chicago Transit Authority? Christian Tool of Affirmation? The list of entries at http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/CTA is long... ;-) Can you explain what CTA means?

Comment: Only one way to find out....

Comment: You can never know until you test it. Look at @Awesome Designer's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its depends on your audiences. You should take A/B testing for with CTA banner and without CTA banner.

You will get more information on this article about CTA

[How to Create Highly Clickable CTA Buttons](https://medium.com/@Atomic_Reach/how-to-create-highly-clickable-cta-buttons-78f904476975)